# How best to convert AMP to HTML

Tags: html, amp-html

If I want to convert a web page from AMP to plain HTML, do I need to change all the amp tags or can I just leave them? I assume I'd need to remove it from the Doctype section. Can I leave amp-animation, amp-img, etc. or do I need to convert everything?

I'm asking this because making an AMP shopping cart and taking payments seemed too difficult and possibly buggy, so I'm switching only the product and payments pages to regular HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Depend on die AMP-tags and what you want in the HTML.
If you want to display the Image you must change the amp-img to img.
In general amp-html tag are not displayed in html.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and converted everything from AMP to regular HTML

Comment: I appreciate your response and taking the time to write an answer. I can't select this as an answer because the question asks for clarity on what AMP code could remain and what needed to be removed. For example: all code removed? No code needs to be removed, it just won't be cached? Some code, and if so, what kinds of code can remain or be removed? It seems this answer is "some code". So to be complete: what code could remain? The "depends on AMP-tags" and "in general" seems to indicate some can stay, so what code can stay? I'm not sure how I received one down vote for asking a question?